# Problem with "dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold" on Linux Bash

Tags: bash, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

while issuing following command in linux bash,

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=192.168.1.5\MSSQLSERVER2017;Database=TestDb;User Id=test;Password=test@987" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models --context AppDbContext -t solid
```

I get this error message:

```
Unrecognized command or argument 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'
```

I figured out the problem that it is being caused by space in "User Id" in the command because when i remove space i get this message.

```
Keyword not supported: 'userid'
```

I tried lots of combinations like putting User\ Id, 'User Id', "User Id", User" "Id and a lot more I found on the internet but I am still stuck on this. How can I solve this?

My EF version:

```
Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools
2.1.4-rtm-31024
```

My dotnet version:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.500
 Commit:    b68b931422

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     arch
OS Version:  
OS Platform: Linux
RID:         arch-x64
Base Path:   /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.1.500/

Host (useful for support):
Version: 2.1.6
Commit:  3f4f8eebd8

.NET Core SDKs installed:
 2.1.500 [/opt/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.6 [/opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

P.S. I've already added "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" package in the project too.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Were you running the command directly on the terminal or via a *.sh file? Because this problem happened to me while issuing the `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` via a *.sh file. I solved it by storing the whole command in a variable and using `eval` to run it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this same issue on Windows. 
[image: dotnet ef scaffold error]

but i fixed it by using the Command below.

```
> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.\;Database=YourDatabase;Trusted_Connection=False; User ID=sa; Password=YourPassword;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Model -c "YourDBContext"
```

In my own case, i tried to figure our what was wrong with my previous command and i got some few answers though they might not be applicable to everyone.

1. Before the "Server" key, i was using a single quote so i changed it to double quote.
2. In my the "." for the server name, i included backslash "\"
3. I enclosed my db context with a double quote.

Although i took all this steps but the truth is that i don't know which one actually worked but i can assure you that the above code works pretty well. However you can checkout an article i found below.
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with .NET scaffolding, but I can tell you that bash is not your problem here. I believe the error you're getting when removing the space from "User Id" is unrelated, and the space is working as intended. Instead you're getting an error that the SqlServer command is unrecognized. This is likely because it is either not installed or the path/permissions are not appropriately set.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/

Comment: Yes, I agree bash is not problem here, It's problem with EF and how it parses that connection string from bash. This exact command works fine in Windows machine so what I mean is there must be some work around for this to accomplish this task in bash.

Comment: On the contrary, it likely has to do with the fact that SqlServer is not appropriately set up on that linux machine.

Comment: The SqlServer is running on another Windows machine in the same network. I followed the official guide:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

Comment: Try adding a semi-colon at the end of the string: `"Server=192.168.1.5\MSSQLSERVER2017;Database=TestDb;User Id=test;Password=test@987;"`

Comment: Still got the same output.

Comment: Might need to escape the \ with \\

Comment: tried that too but not working. moving towards Windows for this now

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Mint 20, I had success doing this:

```sh
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold 'Server=localhost,1433;Database=MyAPICore;User ID=sa;Password=p4ssw0rd!;' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -c 'ApiDbContext' -d -f
```